# How to access on premise Teradata from Azure Databricks

Tags: teradata, azure-virtual-network, azure-databricks

We need to connect to on premise Teradata from Azure Databricks .

Is that possible at all ?

If yes please let me know how .

Comment: did you manage to connect Teradata from Azure Databricks? if yes can you pls share the steps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a virtual network that can connect to on prem then you can deploy your databricks instance into that vnet. See https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/vnet-inject.html.

I assume that there is a spark connector for terradata. I haven't used it myself but I'm sure one exists.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for this information as well and I recently was able to access our Teradata instance from Databricks. Here is how I was able to do it.

Step 1. Check your cloud connectivity.
%sh nc -vz 'jdbcHostname' 'jdbcPort'
- 'jdbcHostName' is your Teradata server.
- 'jdbcPort' is your Teradata server listening port. By default, Teradata listens to the TCP port 1025

Also check out [Databrick’s best practice](https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/aws/vpc-peering.html) on connecting to another infrastructure.

Step 2. Install Teradata JDBC driver.
[Teradata Downloads](https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/jdbc-driver) page provides JDBC drivers by version and archive type. You can also check the [Teradata JDBC Driver Supported Platforms](https://teradata-docs.s3.amazonaws.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/frameset.html) page to make sure you pick the right version of the driver.

Databricks offers multiple ways to install a JDBC library JAR for databases whose drivers are not available in Databricks. Please refer to the [Databricks Libraries](https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/index.html) to learn more and pick the one that is right for you.
Once installed, you should see it listed in the Cluster details page under the Libraries tab.

```
Terajdbc4.jar dbfs:/workspace/libs/terajdbc4.jar
```

Step 3. Connect to Teradata from Databricks.
You can define some variables to let us programmatically create these connections. Since my instance required LDAP, I added LOGMECH=LDAP in the URL. Without LOGMECH=LDAP it returns “username or password invalid” error message.
(Replace the text in italic to the values in your environment)
driver = “com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver”
url = “jdbc:teradata://Teradata_database_server/Database=Teradata_database_name,LOGMECH=LDAP”
table = “Teradata_schema.Teradata_tablename_or_viewname”
user = “your_username”
password = “your_password”

Now that the connection variables are specified, you can create a DataFrame. You can also explicitly set this to a particular schema if you have one already. Please refer to [Spark SQL Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) for more information.

Now, let’s create a DataFrame in Python.

```
My_remote_table = spark.read.format(“jdbc”)\
.option(“driver”, driver)\
.option(“url”, url)\
.option(“dbtable”, table)\
.option(“user”, user)\
.option(“password”, password)\
.load()
```

Now that the DataFrame is created, it can be queried. For instance, you can select some particular columns to select and display within Databricks.

```
display(My_remote_table.select(“EXAMPLE_COLUMN”))
```

Step 4. Create a temporary view or a permanent table.

```
My_remote_table.createOrReplaceTempView(“YOUR_TEMP_VIEW_NAME”)
or
My_remote_table.write.format(“parquet”).saveAsTable(“YOUR_PERMANENT_TABLE_NAME”)
```

Step 3 and 4 can also be combined if the intention is to simply create a table in Databricks from Teradata. Check out the Databricks documentation SQL Databases Using JDBC for other options.

Here is a link to the write-up I published on this topic.
[Accessing Teradata from Databricks for Rapid Experimentation in Data Science and Analytics Projects](https://medium.com/@Tulga.Unlusoy/accessing-teradata-from-databricks-for-rapid-experimentation-in-data-science-and-analytics-projects-4c5e0b558b1)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If you run Azure Databricks, all the data needs to be stored in Azure. But you can call the data using REST API from Teradata and then save data in Azure.